# WPF: How to avoid an image get out of Canvas's borders?

Tags: wpf, canvas, transparency

I have a canvas as an image viewer. Its background is used to place an image and I'd like to put another image on top of it. So, the scenario is like this:

```
 <Canvas Name="VisorCanvas"  Height="514"  Width="720">
   <Canvas.Background>
   <ImageBrush />
   </Canvas.Background>
   <Image Name="foreground"  />
</Canvas>
```

I insert images dynamically in code behind (C#).

The problem is that if the image is too big, then the image goes beyond the Canvas's borders. For instance: I have an irrelevant background image and I want to show a square inside the Canvas panel (on top of its background) through the following way:

- In any case the square's image will be resized.
- if it's smaller than canvas's dimensions, I just show it.
- if it's bigger in whatever dimension (width or height), I need either to crop it or set transparent a part of image. Doing so I achieve a TV mode or something like this, since the figure will always seem "inside" the canvas (although a part is cropped)

How may I do that? I've tried:

- To crop the image by using CroppedBitmap but it's not accurate.
- To use transparency through an additional opacityMask image, but I'd need to create a mask bitmap (with transparency) from the original one and I don't know how to do that.
- To create a "photo" by using RenderTargetBitmap and replacing the image by the result of this method, but I couldn't.

I'd be grateful If someone could shed light on it.

Answer (score 35):

Set `ClipToBounds="True"` in your `Canvas` element, and that will stop the image going beyond the canvas's borders.

You might also want to consider not using an `Image` element. You could use a `Rectangle` with the `Fill` set to an `ImageBrush` because you can then use the `Viewbox` and `Viewport` properties to select which part of the source image you want, and the size of the output you want. (Set `ViewportUnits` to `Absolute` to take precise control over the dimensions of the painted area.)

Comment: ClipToBounds! Fixed some Z Order issues I was having.

Comment: Worked for me. Just to clarify, ClipToBounds should be set on the parent object.

Comment: @TylerPantuso by 'parent' do you mean the `Canvas`? If so, that's exactly what I said in the first sentence. And if not, what do you mean? Are you finding that you need to set it on the Canvas's parent? If so, that's not normal.